# How to solve the closest subset sum problem in Java for 100+ element arrays?

Tags: java, algorithm, np-complete

I have came across a subset sum problem recently. I was able to solve it for smaller arrays using Java earlier, but in this case I have really no idea what should I do. Brute force and recurrence is probably not an option, as I came across out of memory problem.

So, let's say we have an array of **{2500, 3200, 3300}**. We are looking for the **sum closest to the desired number K = 135000**. The main difference is that we can **use numbers from the array multiple times**.

Ok, if we can use them multiple times, then we can change it to more **"traditional"** way - just divide K by each of these numbers - that is **54, 42 and 40** - and **create a new array**, which has those numbers the number of times received from dividing. It would be **{2500, 2500, 2500, ... , ... 3300, 3300}** and the new array would have the **length of 136**. Now this is **much more than 3**.

So - how to solve the closest **subset sum problem**, where we can pick **more than 2 numbers** from the **array of 136 elements or more** using Java?

The thing I want to get is **not only the closest sum**, but also **a list of elements which gave that sum**.

I heard and was reading about dynamic programing, approximation algorithms and genetic algorithms, but unfortunately I have no idea about those. I did genetic algorithm for a different case some time ago, but I am not sure how to use it in this case.

Any ideas? I will be really glad for help.

Comment: How close do you need it? Simple 1/2-approximation would do?

Comment: does it matter how many elements you use to reach the closest sum?

Comment: @Neil As close as possibile.

Comment: @user1984 No, it does not matter. We want to find the closest sum and see the elements that gave that sum.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be purely a question about finding an algorithm, not about how to write the code. Please try https://cs.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not going to solve it for you. but I'll give you the key ideas in pseudocode (aka Python).

We start with a state that represents the following statement: "I don't know how to arrive to any numbers.  The `best` thing I can generate is `0`. I have not yet processed the fact that I could get to `0`."

In data:

```
can_generate = set()
todo = [0]
best = 0
K = 135000
```

What we will do is, while anything is in `todo`, take off a value, see if it is new to us.  If it is, we might update `best`, and possibly add new values to `todo`.  Like this:

```
while len(todo):
    value = todo.pop()
    if value not in can_generate:
        can_generate.add(value)
        if abs(K-value) < abs(K-best):
            best = value
        if value < K:
            for term in [2500, 3200, 3300]:
                todo.append(value + term)
```

Now that we know the values in `can_generate`, we search backwards to find how to get there.

```
answer = []
while 0 < best:
    for term in [3300, 3200, 2500]:
        if best - term in can_generate:
            answer.append(term)
            best -= term
            break
```

Comment: Sir, you are a genius. I will try it in Python first, then I will refactor it to Java. If everything works fine, I will mark it as solved. Thank you!

Comment: And it is working like a charm. Thank you! I didn't know this kind of approach, very clever.